# Heroku Spring Boot Gradle App Deployed but App is crashing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, heroku

I have created Spring Boot Gradle Application with PostgreSQL database and deployed on heroku

```
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/gradle
remote: -----> Gradle app detected
remote: -----> Spring Boot detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Building Gradle app...
remote: -----> executing ./gradlew build -x check
remote:        To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
remote:        Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
remote:        > Task :compileJava
remote:        > Task :processResources
remote:        > Task :classes
remote:        > Task :bootJarMainClassName
remote:        > Task :bootJar
remote:        > Task :jar
remote:        > Task :assemble
remote:        > Task :build
remote:
remote:        BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 10s
remote:        5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 88.2M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v31
remote:        https://lawcase.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/lawcase.git
   464da17..2c2db7c  main -> main
```

App is deployed on heroku with this URL https://lawcase.herokuapp.com, I have developed Rest APIs in my Spring Boot APP,
I have also added ProcFile

```
web: java -jar build/libs/LawCase-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar
```

but when i tried to hit API using URL with Postman

```
 https://lawcase.herokuapp.com/getprofiles
```

I am getting 503 Service Unavailable

here are the heroku logs

```
    2021-11-09T08:13:26.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ahmad.sardar@hotmail.com
2021-11-09T08:13:53.069450+00:00 app[api]: Release v30 created by user ahmad.sardar@hotmail.com
2021-11-09T08:13:53.069450+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 464da17a by user ahmad.sardar@hotmail.com
2021-11-09T08:13:56.790716+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-11-09T08:13:59.975307+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -jar build/libs/LawCase-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar`
2021-11-09T08:14:00.808404+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2021-11-09T08:14:00.883195+00:00 app[web.1]: no main manifest attribute, in build/libs/LawCase-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar
2021-11-09T08:14:01.026544+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-11-09T08:14:01.157284+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-11-09T08:14:01.179061+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-11-09T08:14:04.663230+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -jar build/libs/LawCase-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar`
2021-11-09T08:14:05.581810+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2021-11-09T08:14:05.645857+00:00 app[web.1]: no main manifest attribute, in build/libs/LawCase-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar
2021-11-09T08:14:05.769007+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-11-09T08:14:06.249030+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-11-09T08:14:07.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-11-09T08:14:45.278393+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lawcase.herokuapp.com request_id=788e94d4-a03c-4df8-a9aa-d1b68cc69c55 fwd="39.45.237.31" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-11-09T08:14:46.771103+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lawcase.herokuapp.com request_id=35c2d34e-95f2-473c-96f5-b25306390781 fwd="39.45.237.31" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-11-09T08:15:09.157754+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/getprofiles" host=lawcase.herokuapp.com request_id=dfc5e5f1-1ab8-4dd4-9677-c6557e5dae38 fwd="39.45.237.31" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I have tried different solutions from stackoverflow

[Heroku jar deployment of Spring Boot with Maven Application giving code=H10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46912667/heroku-jar-deployment-of-spring-boot-with-maven-application-giving-code-h10)

[Heroku error code H10 when Spring Boot app is deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343432/heroku-error-code-h10-when-spring-boot-app-is-deployed)

[Spring Boot on Heroku - H10 "app crash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711333/spring-boot-on-heroku-h10-app-crash)

[How can resolve 503 (Service Unavailable) after GET/POST on Spring Boot and Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62222288/how-can-resolve-503-service-unavailable-after-get-post-on-spring-boot-and-hero?noredirect=1#comment110051038_62222288)

[heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61064544/herokuweb-1-state-changed-from-starting-to-crashed)

But I am unable to solve my problem and my app is not working, could anyone please help how to properly deploy and up my APP on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Answering because I can't comment. A couple thoughts. You may not need a Procfile for a Spring Boot app since there is a built-in web server (unless you want to override something). Also found [this](https://itqna.net/questions/51592/heroku-server-h10-code-error-spring-boot-project) similar scenario where it was a postgres driver issue.